# totally bounded set and pairwise disjoint balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $K\subset X$ be totally bounded. We are given some arbitrary $\epsilon >0$.  Let $B\epsilon$ be a family of $\epsilon$ sized balls, such that any 2 balls from this family are disjoint. Assume $B\epsilon$ has infinite cardinality. Is it true to say that $K$ intersects a finite number of balls from the family $B\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes . By  definition  of  totally  boundedness.

Comment: This is not the definition of totally boundedness. The definition is that a totally bounded set can be covered by finitely many $\epsilon$ balls. Here they do not even intersect. And clearly you do not know they cover all of K.

Comment: @user118494 if you have an explanation to your answer, please ellaborate

Comment: I may be wrong since I see an answer posted negating it with an example  but this is what I thought  : Let $K$ intersect  infinitely  many  balls. And  if  they  do  not  cover  all  of  $K$ let $K_{0}$ be the subset  of $K$  that that is  equal  to  $K\cap \{B_{\epsilon}\}$ . Now  subset  of a  totally  bounded  set  is  totally  bounded  so  $K_{0}$  is  totally  bounded  and  hence  only  finitely  many  of  the  $B_{\epsilon} $'s  are  required  to   cover  $K_{0}$ .  Since  the  $B_{\epsilon}$'s  do  not  intersect , the  number  of  such  balls  intersecting  $K$  should  be  finite .

Comment: @user118494 The total boundedness of a set $K_0$ means that it can be covered by a finite number of $\epsilon$ sized balls, and not means that *any* cover of $K_0$ by $\epsilon$ sized balls has a finite subcover.

Comment: But your argument works when the set $K_0$ is compact (for instance, when it is closed and the space $(X, d)$ is complete) and all balls of the family $ B\epsilon $ are open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO.Let $ N$ be the positive integers Let $X$ be the set of real sequences $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ for which there is at most one $n>2$  with $x_n \ne 0$. Let $ d((x_n)_{n \in N},(y_n)_{n\in N})=\sum_{n \in N}|x_n-y_n|.$ (Of course at most $3$ terms in the summation are non-zero.) Let $$K=\{(x_n)_{n \in N} \in X : 0\le x_1 \le 1 \text{ and } x_n=0\text{ for } n>1\}.$$ $K$ is compact so it is totally bounded.Take real sequences $(A_j)_{j \in N}$ and $(B_j)_{j\in N}$ where $$0<B_{j+1}<A_j<B_j<1\text{ for  }j\in N.$$ Now for each $j$ let $ D_j$ be the open disc of radius $1$ centered at $$C_j=(\sigma_{j,n})_{n\in N}$$ where $$\sigma_{j,1}=(A_j+B_j)/2 \text{ and } \sigma_{j,j}=1-(B_j-A_j)/2.$$ (All the other co-ordinates of  $C_j$ are $0$.). Now I leave it to you to confirm that $\{D_j\}_{j\in N}$ is a pair-wise disjoint family and every D_j  intersects K.

Comment: I do not need the centers to be disjoint, I need the balls $D_j$ for $j\in N$ to be pairwise disjoint

Comment: the balls are disjoint. i made a typo.

Comment: What happens when j=1? Your 2 definition for sigma do not coincide in this case

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following.

In general, the answer is negative. Let $X=\ell^1$ and $\{e_n\}$  be the standard orts of the space $\ell^1$. Put $K=\{e_1/n: n\in\Bbb N\}$, $\epsilon=1$ and the set of centers of the closed balls of the family $B\epsilon$ is $\{e_n+e_1/n: n\in\Bbb N \}$.

Comment: Interesting... You gave me food for thought that is for sure...

Comment: The same idea as mine but a lot easier to describe and to verify.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky is it necessary that the balls be closed?

Comment: @AvivEshed In user254665's counterexample the balls are open.